# telegram price bot - function loop

Tags: telegram-bot

I am trying to make a telegram price bot but I am running into an issue.
works fine, but I can't set the bot to send me the updated price every 5 minutes (or more).

Any solution?
Thanks!

my code

```
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
from tracker import get_prices

telegram_bot_token = "mybot"

updater = Updater(token=telegram_bot_token, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher


def start(update, context):
    chat_id = update.effective_chat.id
    message = ""

    crypto_data = get_prices()
    for i in crypto_data:
        coin = crypto_data[i]["coin"]
        price = crypto_data[i]["price"]
        change_day = crypto_data[i]["change_day"]
        change_hour = crypto_data[i]["change_hour"]
        message += f" {coin}={price:,.5f}$ \nHour Change: {change_hour:.3f}%\nDay Change: {change_day:.3f}%\n\n"

    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)


dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
updater.start_polling()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different bot, like for example @GroupHelpBot, with built-in capability to automate the execution. For more details, please also check: [How to loop inside a custom Telegram bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69232739/how-to-loop-inside-a-custom-telegram-bot)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).