# How to loop inside a custom Telegram bot?

Tags: telegram-bot

We are trying to make a telegram price bot but running into an issue that could be solved using third party code, however we can't set the bot to send us the updated price every 5 minutes (or more) WITHOUT USING THIRD PARTY SOLUTIONS for security reasons.

How to loop from INSIDE this code, without using another third party Telegram bot?

Here is the code

```
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
from tracker import get_prices

telegram_bot_token = "mybot"

updater = Updater(token=telegram_bot_token, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher


def start(update, context):
    chat_id = update.effective_chat.id
    message = ""

    crypto_data = get_prices()
    for i in crypto_data:
        coin = crypto_data[i]["coin"]
        price = crypto_data[i]["price"]
        change_day = crypto_data[i]["change_day"]
        change_hour = crypto_data[i]["change_hour"]
        message += f" {coin}={price:,.5f}$ \nHour Change: {change_hour:.3f}%\nDay Change: {change_day:.3f}%\n\n"

    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)


dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
updater.start_polling()
```

Any solution that correctly sends one message at a time without appending to the previous one? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to do this.

The first would be with a simple `time.sleep()` in a `while` loop:

```py
import time

def start(update, context):
    chat_id = update.effective_chat.id
    while True:
        message = ""
        crypto_data = get_prices()
        for i in crypto_data:
            coin = crypto_data[i]["coin"]
            price = crypto_data[i]["price"]
            change_day = crypto_data[i]["change_day"]
            change_hour = crypto_data[i]["change_hour"]
            message += f" {coin}={price:,.5f}$ \nHour Change:{change_hour:.3f}%\nDay Change: {change_day:.3f}%\n\n"


        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)
        time.sleep(300)
```

Another method might be using a background process scheduler, but you would probably refactor your `start` function and only schedule the part that creates/sends the message. (The part inside the while loop)

[Advanced Python Scheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/) (`pip install apscheduler`) is a fantastic library for this, but it is a third party library, so maybe not appropriate for you. I have used it on many projects however.

EDIT:

Here's an example of scheduling with `apscheduler`:

```py
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

def message_loop(chat_id, bot):
    message = ""
    crypto_data = get_prices()
    for i in crypto_data:
        coin = crypto_data[i]["coin"]
        price = crypto_data[i]["price"]
        change_day = crypto_data[i]["change_day"]
        change_hour = crypto_data[i]["change_hour"]
        message += f" {coin}={price:,.5f}$ \nHour Change: {change_hour:.3f}%\nDay Change: {change_day:.3f}%\n\n"
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)


def start(update, context):
    chat_id = update.effective_chat.id
    bot = context.bot
    scheduler.add_job(message_loop, 'interval', minutes=5, args=(chat_id, bot))
    scheduler.start()

# You might want to also add a stop function to your bot:

def stop():
    scheduler.shutdown()

dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("stop", stop))
updater.start_polling()
```

Comment: Thank you! So, the first example works ("import time") but not "import time.sleep"; however, it appends the new message to the old one, so it piles up very long messages... Any patch you can add to avoid this and fix it for good?

Comment: sorry! my mistake, you need to move the message variable declaration inside the while loop... I've edited the answer

Comment: Thank you! I have also fixed the original post to clarify that the message should not be appended

Answer (score -1):

you should try to add setinterval or a pure millis() function and you will be good to go